# ActionMailer help, paste email from session!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Notifier.rb

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def inquiry_notification(inquiry)
     recipients     inquiry.respondent.email
     from           "#{@laz.email}"
     subject        "Survey"
     content_type "text/html"
  end
end
```

Part of Controller.rb

```
...
 @laz = User.find(:all)

        respondents.each do |r|
          inquiry = Inquiry.create(:question_id => @question.id, :respondent_id => r.id, :is_answered => 0)
          Notifier.deliver_inquiry_notification(inquiry)  
        end
....
```

I need to paste into "FROM" (notifier.rb) email that user has.

For example: session[:user].email <- paste this , because i work with sessions and i have many users (admins and auditors).

Comment: If you want to delete your question, click the delete link. Editing to gibberish is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just add additional parameter to your inquiry_notification method like this:

```
def inquiry_notification(inquiry, from_email)
  recipients   inquiry.respondent.email
  from         from_email
  subject      "Survey"
  content_type "text/html"
end
```

If you dont want to do so, you can use for example Thread.current:
in controller

```
Thread.current[:email] = 'test@email.com'
```

in Notifier

```
def inquiry_notification(inquiry)
  recipients     inquiry.respondent.email
  from           Thread.current[:email]
  subject        "Survey"
  content_type "text/html"
end
```